# Restricting data based upon value in the picklist

Tags: assignment-rules, territory-management

I have a scenario in which I need to restrict some records(accounts) which should be seen to a particular person only if the value in the picklist Type='Client'.How can I implement this scenario.Currently there isn't any assignment rules available on accounts.How would I implement this scenario?

Comment: Do you need to restrict the entire record or only certain fields on the record? If it's the entire record, implementing RecordTypes would be the way to go. You may also want to consider implementing PublisherActions for creating them. Otherwise, until that field is set, everyone else will have access to them. Once it gets changed, they'll immediately lose if they'll immediately lose it if not an admin.

Comment: Hi,there are 10 accounts having client type field under 10 users.I want to restrict these 10 accounts so that only that user can see those records.The 10 accounts have different account owners.

Comment: Are you saying that you have 10 accounts in total you want to restrict among 10 total users who also own some of the accounts? It's unclear whether you also want to restrict the account owners from seeing the records they own if of type 'Client'? Also, what's the OWD on Accounts? Would be odd for the account owner not to have access to the records for their account. Please clarify that requirement or total number of users vs restricted users.

Comment: Yes,I want to restrict 10 account owners from seeing their own records if they own of type clients.

Answer (score 1):

A RecordType won't prevent the owner of an Account record from viewing their Account, just the page layout for that RecordType.

Record Types alone won't do what you want. You're going to want to transfer ownership of the 'Client' Accounts to the User that you want be the one who can only see and edit those records. You're also going to want to change the OWD to private on Accounts. At the same time, you'll need to create permission-sets/Sharing Groups so the 10 users who need to see the other types of Accounts (and any others in your org that also need need to see them) can have either read or read-write permissions on the Accounts you'd like them to share amongst themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider 2 things here

1. Create profiles for different users to manage access.
2. Create record types for records (Accounts & contacts) and assign visibility of record type based on profile of that user.

This is how you can restrict visibility of the accounts to users based on their profile access.

For giving more access to any user but not profile, you can create permission sets which will give access to that account to the users who's profile is not allowing them to access that contact.

> Ex.
>
> Account record type: Sales contacts
>
> Account record type: Client
>
> contacts Profile A : access level - Sales contacts
>
> Profile B : access level - Client contacts
>
> Special permission set to user A in Profile A : access to Client
>   contacts.

Hope this solves your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain me in a layman language,I am confused where did the contacts came from?

Comment: That was just reference to account, just a naming convention. You can put any name you want there.

Comment: You're welcome.
Here's what I assumed from your question: 
>Your Org wide defaults are Private
>You already know that for different record type, you have to create different page layouts, and also you know how to play with permissions for read/edit etc.

Please mark this answer as resolution if this resolved your question. Cheers!